# cpuset.cpu_exclusive doesnt gives desired results in libvirt

Tags: virtualization, libvirt, cgroups

So, basically the flag cpuset.cpu_excluvie restrict the the processor to run processes present in a particular cpuset only. Now, I have a VM with 3 cpus and I launched three VM instances making one cpu exclusive for each of them. That means, my three instances have a CPU exclusive for them and my host has only three CPUs. What I am not able to understand is how I am able to do work on the system? Do I have a hidden CPU somewhere?! Or the exclusiveness property is not that exclusive?

Answer (score 1):

> ### cpuset.cpu_exclusive
>
> contains a flag (0 or 1) that specifies whether cpusets other than this one and its parents and children can share the CPUs specified for this cpuset. By default (0), CPUs are not allocated exclusively to one cpuset.

Basically, it means that the root cgroup also have access to these CPUs. Since most of the processes are assigned to the root cgroup, they can use all the CPUs.